# Trying to define one of Euler's approximations to pi, getting unsupported operand type(s) for 'list and 'int'

Tags: python, pi, approximation

I am trying to define a function which will approximate `pi` in python using one of Euler's methods. His formula is as follows:
[image: formula]

My code so far is this:

```
def pi_euler1(n):
    numerator = list(range(2 , n))
    for i in numerator:
        j = 2
        while i * j <= numerator[-1]:
            if i * j in numerator:
                numerator.remove(i * j)
            j += 1
    for k in numerator:
        if (k + 1) % 4 == 0:
            denominator = k + 1
        else:
            denominator = k - 1
    #Because all primes are odd, both numbers inbetween them are divisible by 2,
    #and by extension 1 of the 2 numbers is divisible by 4
    term = numerator / denominator
```

I know this is wrong, and also incomplete. I'm just not quite sure what the **TypeError** that I mentioned earlier actually means. I'm just quite stuck with it, I want to create a list of the terms and then find their products. Am I on the right lines?

Update:
I have worked ways around this, fixing the clearly obvious errors that were prevalent thanks to msconi and Johanc, now with the following code:

```
import math
def pi_euler1(n):
    numerator = list(range(2 , 13 + math.ceil(n*(math.log(n)+math.log(math.log(n))))))
    denominator=[]
    for i in numerator:
        j = 2
        while i * j <= numerator[-1]:
            if (i * j) in numerator:
                numerator.remove(i * j)
            j += 1
    numerator.remove(2)
        for k in numerator:
            if (k + 1) % 4 == 0:
                denominator.append(k+1)
            else:
                denominator.append(k-1)
        a=1
        for i in range(n):
            a *= numerator[i] / denominator[i]
        return 4*a
```

This seems to work, when I tried to plot a graph of the errors from pi in a semilogy axes scale, I was getting a domain error, but i needed to change the upper bound of the range to n+1 because log(0) is undefined. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code with some small modifications to get it working:

```
import math
def pi_euler1(n):
    lim = n * n + 4
    numerator = list(range(3, lim, 2))
    for i in numerator:
        j = 3
        while i * j <= numerator[-1]:
            if i * j in numerator:
                numerator.remove(i * j)
            j += 2
    euler_product = 1
    for k in numerator[:n]:
        if (k + 1) % 4 == 0:
            denominator = k + 1
        else:
            denominator = k - 1
        factor = k / denominator
        euler_product *= factor
    return euler_product * 4

print(pi_euler1(3))
print(pi_euler1(10000))
print(math.pi)
```

Output:

```
3.28125
3.148427801913721
3.141592653589793
```

Remarks:

- You only want the odd primes, so you can start with a list of odd numbers.
- `j` can start with `3` and increment in steps of 2. In fact, `j` can start at `i` because all the multiples of `i` smaller than `i*i` are already removed earlier.
- In general it is very bad practise to remove elements from the list over which you are iterating. See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating). Internally, Python uses an index into the list over which it iterates. Coincidently, this is not a problem in this specific case, because only numbers larger than the current are removed.
- Also, removing elements from a very long list is very slow, as each time the complete list needs to be moved to fill the gap. Therefore, it is better to work with two separate lists.
- You didn't calculate the resulting product, nor did you return it.
- As you notice, this formula converges very slowly.
- As mentioned in the comments, the previous version interpreted `n` as the limit for highest prime, while in fact `n` should be the number of primes. I adapted the code to rectify that. In the above version with a crude limit; the version below tries a tighter approximation for the limit.

Here is a reworked version, without removing from the list you're iterating. Instead of removing elements, it just marks them. This is much faster, so a larger `n` can be used in a reasonable time:

```
import math
def pi_euler_v3(n):
    if n < 3:
        lim = 6
    else:
        lim = n*n
        while lim / math.log(lim) / 2 > n:
            lim //= 2
    print(n, lim)

    numerator = list(range(3, lim, 2))
    odd_primes = []
    for i in numerator:
        if i is not None:
            odd_primes.append(i)
            if len(odd_primes) >= n:
                break
            j = i
            while i * j < lim:
                numerator[(i*j-3) // 2] = None
                j += 2
    if len(odd_primes) != n:
       print(f"Wrong limit calculation, only {len(odd_primes)} primes instead of {n}")
    euler_product = 1
    for k in odd_primes:
        denominator = k + 1 if k % 4 == 3 else k - 1
        euler_product *= k / denominator
    return euler_product * 4

print(pi_euler_v2(100000))
print(math.pi)
```

Output:

```
3.141752253548891
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: If you start from `numerator = list(range(3, n, 2))` you won't get the list of the `n` first primes, which is how the problem is defined.

Comment: "...which computes the value of the first n terms in the product..."

Comment: Indeed, this is a different interpretation of `n`. The solution would be to multiply n with some large enough number to get the array limit.

Comment: I would rather build the prime list incrementally. but I'm not an expert on prime algorithms. starting from a list with random length doesn't sound like a good general approach, imo

Comment: Indeed, building the list in chunks the additional advantage to need much less memory. You only need memory for a fixed chunk length, together with memory to store the `n` primes.  The new version above tries to calculate a good limit.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, and thank you very much for your answer, would it not be more efficient to work out the complexity for the number of primes in a range 1,n. And change the range accordingly? I think it's something like ```math.ceil(n*(math.log(n)+math.log(math.log(n)))```

Comment: Feel free to use a better way to calculate the limit.  The only simple formula I found was `n < lim / log(lim)`, but that doesn't have an easy inverse. So I made a crude approximation, which could be refined if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In `term = numerator / denominator` you are dividing a list by a number, which doesn't make sense. Divide `k` by the denominator in the loop in order to use the `numerator` *element* for each of the equation's factors one by one. Then you could multiply them repeatedly to the term `term *= i / denominator`, which you initialize in the beginning as `term = 1`.

Another issue is the first loop, which won't give you the first `n` prime numbers. For example, for `n=3`, `list(range(2 , n)) = [2]`. Therefore, the only prime you will get is 2.

Comment: Thank you, I've done all you suggested and changed the range of primes to n+1 so as to include n, I've also added a third for loop to iterate i/denominator as you said. My output for pi_euler(10) was 0.04486... and larger numbers just get very small float outputs, I'm going to fiddle around with it see where I've gone wrong. Thank you though, I now have the premise of how it works, I think

Comment: changing the range of primes to n+1 won't be enough, since in the general case you don't know what your largest prime will be (e.g. the 3rd prime is 5, not included in n+1=4). Better: start with an empty list, find the next primes, and keep appending until the list has length `n`. It should be easy to find efficient prime generating algorithms.